# JSON nested object shows empty in rest debugger and RestResponse (XE6)

Tags: json, rest, delphi, c++builder

I use C++Builder XE6 Pro and have the following JSON response (see the [full response here](https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty.json?conditions[q]=Bank%20Millennium)):

```json
[
{
"id":"10186",
"dataset":"krs_podmioty",
"url":"https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty/10186",
"mp_url":"https://mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty/10186",
"schema_url":"https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/schemas/dane/krs_podmioty.json",
"global_id":"3157847",
"slug":"bank-millennium",
"score":12.13878,
"data":
{
  "krs_podmioty.nazwa_organu_reprezentacji":"ZARZĄD",
  "krs_podmioty.dotacje_ue_beneficjent_id":"0",
  "krs_podmioty.liczba_prokurentow":0,
  ...
  "gpw":true
}
...
]
```

I am using REST components, but when I try to parse this, both in the REST Debugger and at design/run-time, I am getting empty values for the `"dataset":"krs_podmioty"` elements, but the `"gpw":true` elements show correctly.

I've choosen the JSON root element as DataObject, and marked Nested
and set NestedElementDepth to 3.  I have tried another settings as well, but without success.

How to get the `"dataset":"krs_podmioty"` values correctly ?

Comment: UTF-8 encoding issue of some accentuated characters?

Comment: Arnaud Bouchez: Doubt it, parsing didn't fail since i am getting "data":"gpw" proper value wchich is last on the list.

Comment: XE6 JSON parser is so odd that it may gracefully fail... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'm able to read those values:

```
uses
  System.Json;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 jsonText: string;
 jsonArray: TJsonArray;
 dataObj: TJsonObject;
 Jobj: TJsonObject;
 krsPodmiotyNazwaOrganuReprezentacjiValue: TJsonValue;
 krsPodmiotyDotacjeUeBeneficjentIdValue: TJsonValue;
 krsPodmiotyLiczbaProkurentowValue: TJsonValue;
begin
 jsonText := '[{Your JSON content here}]';
 Jobj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(jsonText) as TJsonObject;
 jsonArray :=Jobj.GetValue('Dataobject') as TJsonArray;
 dataObj := (jsonArray.Items[0] as TJsonObject).GetValue('data') as  TJsonObject;
  krsPodmiotyNazwaOrganuReprezentacjiValue := dataObj.GetValue('krs_podmioty.nazwa_organu_reprezentacji');
  krsPodmiotyDotacjeUeBeneficjentIdValue := dataObj.GetValue('krs_podmioty.dotacje_ue_beneficjent_id');
  krsPodmiotyLiczbaProkurentowValue := dataObj.GetValue('krs_podmioty.liczba_prokurentow');
  MessageDlg(krsPodmiotyNazwaOrganuReprezentacjiValue.Value, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0, mbOK);
  MessageDlg(krsPodmiotyDotacjeUeBeneficjentIdValue.Value, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0, mbOK);
  MessageDlg(krsPodmiotyLiczbaProkurentowValue.Value, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0, mbOK);
end;
```

However, if you are not using anything from the `System.Json` namespace, this might not answer your question.

Comment: Edited to actually compile and run , kinda hoped for dataset solution but documentation states that not every data object could be mapped as DataSet so i assume this is the case. Anyway accepting answer.